# Pde: $u_{t}+6uu_{x}+u_{xxx}=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Help me please to solve this pde.

$u_{t}+6uu_{x}+u_{xxx}=0$
with boundary conditions $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty }u(x,t)=\lim_{x \to \pm \infty }u_{x}(x,t)=\lim_{x \to \pm \infty }u_{xx}(x,t)=0$

a. Show that the energy $E(t)=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }u^{2}(x,t)dx$ is conserves.
Hint: integration by parts

b. Prove that for initial condition $u(x,0)=0$ exist only a trivial solution.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

(a) Multiply by $u$ and take the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \, dx$:

$0=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}uu_t + 6\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u^2u_x + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}uu_{xxx}$

Dealing with each part:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}uu_t = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac d {dt} \frac 1 2 u^2 = \frac 1 2 \frac d {dt}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u^2 $

$ 6\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u^2u_x = 6 \frac 1 3 u^3|^\infty_{-\infty}  = 2(lim_{x\to \infty}u(x,t)^3 - lim_{x\to -\infty}u(x,t)^3) = 0$

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}uu_{xxx} = uu_{xx}|^\infty_{-\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u_xu_{xx} = 0 - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u_xu_{xx} = - \frac 1 2 (u_x)^2 |_{-\infty}^{\infty} = 0$

Yielding:

$\frac d {dt}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u^2  = 0$

As required.

(b) From (a) and the extra condition we conclude that $\forall t\, \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u^2  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u^2 |_{t=0}  = 0$, therefore $u^2$, and thus $u$, is zero almost everywhere. Assuming a continuous solution, there is only the trivial one.